# A user's anonymized posts can be seen on their profile under "Top Network Posts"

Tags: support, profile-page, post-disassociation

I was browsing a user's profile and clicked on one of their posts under "Top Network Posts". It was a question, since the path of the URL of the post did not end with a numeric post ID.

The OP of the question showed up as "anon". I am not familiar with what happens after dissociation, but this made me guess that this is a post of this user who has dissociated it.

I am not including the profile of the user for the user's privacy. Let me know if I need to provide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**contact us**](/contact) link at the bottom of the page to send us the link to the affected profile and the question, and we'll correct it.

We had a bug where the post disassociations didn't correctly propagate to the network profile. It's been fixed a couple weeks ago, so going forward this should no longer be a problem... but there are likely some profiles still out there that need to be fixed up.